# Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_all() on boolean

Tags: php, html, json, mysqli

I am trying to make al the records in my database to a JSON format so i can use it in an app from me, but then i got this error `<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function fetch_all() on boolean` i have tried changing `fetch_all to fetchall` but it did not help. this is my code that i use:

```
<html>
    <body>
<?php
//Converting db values into json data

header('Content-type:application/json');

$conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','') or die(mysql_error());
$sql= 'SELECT * FROM wtd';
$rs=$conn->query($sql);

$data = $rs->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($data);


?>
        </body>
</html>
```

I hope anyone can help me i am on a time limit.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you have **not** selected any database. You can set the database like this:

```
$conn = new mysql('localhost', 'root', '', '<NAME_OF_DATABASE>');
```

Since you have not selected the database `$conn->query()` will return `FALSE`.

Comment: thank you it worked! but when i reload the page i dont see any of my things that are in the mysql database table like on my website : http://what-to-do.net63.net/things.php

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking?

Answer (score 0):

You must select a database:

```
$conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','', '**database**') or die(mysql_error());
```